# Infer order of insertion into BST

Tags: binary-search-tree

It seems several possible orders of insertion would create the BST in the image below.

E.g: F C S B E R D

What conditions regarding the order would ensure the same result please? I'm thinking as long as the entries for a given level are entered before those on the next level?

[image]

Comment: The preorder traversal can return the same tree, without satisfying that condition.

Comment: Your observation is near the truth. The necessary and sufficient requirement is parents must be inserted before children. Or, what is equivalent, ancestors must be inserted beforehand. More specifically, if node X is an ancestor of node Y, then X must be inserted before Y.